# Como añadir varios entornos de desarrollo?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, variables-de-configuración

Resulta que estoy empezando con MySQL y PHP, ya añadí éste último a la variable de entorno Path, pero a la hora de usar MySQL no me deja usarlo y tengo que añadirlo también como variable de entorno Path. Esto hace que funcione MySQL pero que ya no me funcione PHP, y viceversa.
Alguna solución ???
[image: Asi es la interfaz de como configurarlo, como ven solo puedo añadir una :C]

Comment: Tiene pinta que estas sobreescribiendo el path completamente cada vez que lo editas. Muy mal hecho. Seguramente ahora te dejaran de funcionar muchas otras cosas porque debes haber borrado sin querer lo que ya tenias antes. El Path se puede editar y agregar nuevas rutas separadas por punto y coma, pero nunca borrar del todo para agregar tan solo una tal como estas haciendo.  Vete a saber lo que tenias antes y el resultado imprevisto que tendras a partir de ahora en tu ordenador segun los programas que ya tenian algo en el path antes que lo sobreescribieras.

Comment: En efecto, recien me di cuenta porque en los tutoriales que habia visto la interfaz era otra, lo bueno es que el path anterior lo copié y lo tengo, tendría que agregar el ; nomas no? graciasssss

Comment: Si, creo que es el punto y coma (hace milenios que no toco windows)... comprueba viendo el path que has guardado a ver que usan para separar las rutas, y agrega las que necesites a continuación usando el mismo separador.. que suerte has tenido! :-D

Comment: eso tiene que ser porque debes añadir dos rutas si no recuerdo mal o si no separarlo con punto y comas ``;`` o ``,`` no lo recuerdo bien pero estoy con @masterguru tambien existe otra web llamada [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) en ese sitio te pueden ayudar mejor que aqui :)